# How can we alternate axis tick labels in lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I wish to alternate Y-axis tick labels between left and right side. I checked the `xyplot` documentation, but couldn't find any argument that would help with the goal. I tried using `alternating` argument to `scales` but it only accepts an integer or a vector with two integers. I wish to alternate tick labels since I want to visualise conditional modes estimated by a linear mixed effects model - with the default setting, sometimes, the Y-axis becomes too crowded.

Expected output:

```
z| --- |
 | --- |y
x| --- |
 | --- |w
 .  .
 .  .
 .  .
b| --- |
 | --- |a
```

Failed attempt:

```
library(lattice)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
latticeDF <- tibble(x = runif(26), y = letters)
lattice::dotplot(y ~ x, 
                 data = latticeDF, 
                 scales = list(y = list(labels = letters, 
                                       alternating = rep(c(1, 2), 13))))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alternating` argument determines on which side of each panel the *whole axis* is displayed. It does not support alternating labels to either side of the same panel. For this you would need a secondary axis, as produced by `latticeExtra::doubleYScale`.

In your case, that might look something like:

```r
dp1 <- dotplot(y ~ x, data = latticeDF, 
               scales = list(y = list(labels = replace(letters, 1:13 * 2, ''))))

dp2 <- dotplot(y ~ x, data = latticeDF, 
               scales = list(y = list(labels = replace(letters, 1:13*2-1, ''))))

latticeExtra::doubleYScale(dp1, dp2, use.style = FALSE, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you are interested, you could do the same thing in ggplot like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(latticeDF, aes(x, as.numeric(factor(y)))) + 
  geom_point(color = '#0080fe') +
  scale_y_continuous('y', breaks = 1:13 * 2 - 1, minor_breaks =  1:13 * 2,
                     labels = ~letters[.x],
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x, NULL, breaks = 1:13 * 2, 
                                         labels = letters[1:13 * 2])) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.2, color = 'gray'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.2, color = 'gray'))
```

[image]